# Why did Dan Kaminsky say that Bitcoin is dependent on the Federal Reserve?

Tags: economic-theory, block, bitcoin-economy, macroeconomics

[Dan Kaminsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Kaminsky) embed [a custom message](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=BUB3dygQ) in a block, which reads "BitCoin's new dependency upon [...] BERNANKE". Why did he say that Bitcoin is dependent on the Federal Reserve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once upon a time someone used Bitcoin's ability to embed arbitrary text inside a transaction to put an [ASCII Art Ben Bernanke](http://pastebin.com/ZqqFEqkc) into the blockchain. Referring to the fact that current blocks must still reference the Bernanke block as a "dependency" rounds out the joke.

Comment: Well, there's my giggle for the evening.